# MySQL How do you return the UNION of these two queries?

Tags: mysql

How do you get the UNION of these two queries:

SELECT dom,sub FROM table WHERE table.dom = X  OR  table.sub = X

SELECT dom,sub FROM table WHERE table.dom = Y  OR  table.sub = Y

dom and sub are integers, both queries return a set of integers, how do you then get the union of these two sets??

Any assistance appreciated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have got an answer using UNION, but why not just

```
SELECT dom,sub FROM table 
  WHERE table.dom = X OR table.sub = X OR table.dom = Y OR table.sub = Y
```

or

```
SELECT dom,sub FROM table 
  WHERE table.dom in (X,Y)  OR table.sub in (X,Y)
```

(assuming you are indeed talking about the same table in both queries)?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT dom,sub FROM table WHERE table.dom = X OR table.sub = X
UNION
SELECT dom,sub FROM table WHERE table.dom = Y OR table.sub = Y
```

...

Answer (score 1):

Following query will remove similar records i.e. will show only distinct

```
SELECT dom,sub FROM table WHERE table.dom = X OR table.sub = X
UNION
SELECT dom,sub FROM table WHERE table.dom = Y OR table.sub = Y
```

if you want all records ,use

```
SELECT dom,sub FROM table WHERE table.dom = X OR table.sub = X
UNION ALL
SELECT dom,sub FROM table WHERE table.dom = Y OR table.sub = Y
```